# Running php in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am making an application on my server, where the user uploads an image through some HTML combined with javascript.

The user finds an image on the computer through

```
<form action="uploadimage.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filnavn:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="100000" />
```

Then the point behind the javascript, is to validate on the users image

```
if(picture_headline.value == "" || picture_uploaded.value == "" || !ischecked)
{
   // Don't execute, stay on same site
}
else
{
   // execute php and upload image
}
```

the php is an upload image php script

```
<?php 
// The file is being uploaded into the folder "upload"
$target = "/navnesutten.eu/facebook/uploads/"; 
// add the original filename of our target path
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 
// Moves the uploaded file into correct folder
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

I must say I am a bit confused here, since I have only been working with html, php and javascript for a few days now.

Am I totally off or what?

I found some "simple" examples online, which I put on my server through cuteFTP, but everytime i press upload, the website just sends me to the .php file and says the site doesn't exist.

Comment: Java != Javascript.

Comment: Do you have a PHP server set up and running?

Comment: You'll need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) for what you want.

Comment: There's a categorical difference between Java and JavaScript.  Are you sure uploadimage.php exists in the same path as the page with the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each array key in `$_FILES` corresponds with the `name` attribute of a file field in the form, so to match your form it should be `'file'` rather than `'uploaded'` or `'uploadedfile'`:

```
<?php 
// The file is being uploaded into the folder "upload"
$target = "/navnesutten.eu/facebook/uploads/"; 
// add the original filename of our target path
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) ; 
$ok=1; 
// Moves the uploaded file into correct folder
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Boann points out you're trying to access a non-existent file in your PHP code ("uploaded" and "uploadedfile" rather than "file" (which is what you named the field in your HTML form)).

But regarding "running PHP from JavaScript": You don't have to. The JavaScript should *only* return false if the form is invalid. If it's valid you don't need to do anything and the form will submit, in turn running your PHP script:

```
form.onsubmit = function () {
    if (!formIsValid()) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

If the form is invalid it won't submit (the `return false` bit (you could use `event.preventDefault()` instead)), if it *is* valid nothing will happen and the form will do what it does (ie submit the data to the server).

Comment: The code you wrote. Is it something I will need in my code? My code ends with the if else.
if will return false
else will return true
Will this really execute the upload_file.php ?
Don't I need some code somewhere to make that happen ?

Comment: As long as your form points to your script (`action="upload_file.php"`) the form data will be sent to your script unless the JS returns false. Which it should only do when the form is invalid. When the form is valid (your `else`) nothing needs to be done from JS. The form just needs to submit normally. You should definitely check in your upload_file.php for form invalidity as well since people can just disable JS.